# Chaining observables RxJava

Tags: android, observable, rx-java, chain

I'm trying to make a chain of obserables in this way

**1 Step (order is not important here so they can run simultaneously)**

```
Task_User_Login.run();   -> Completable
downloadListOfStreets(); -> Completable
```

**2 Step has to be executed AFTER Step 1 (order inside is not important here so they can run simultaneously both have to be merged)**

```
downloadListOfProducts();    -> Observable<Object>
downloadListOfIngredients(); -> Observable<Object>
```

**3 Step has to be executed AFTER Step 2**

```
logoutDummySession();   -> Completable
```

**EDIT**

I've tried several things...but I cannot figure out how to make it work. This is my latest code

```
(Task_User_Login.run(AppConstants.defaultLoginParameters))
                .andThen(downloadListOfStreets().doOnComplete(this::onStreetsDownloaded))
                    .andThen(Observable.merge(downloadListOfProducts(), downloadListOfIngredients()))
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .doOnNext(item -> updateItemsDownloaded())
                        .doOnError(error -> downloadCompleted.postValue(Response.error(error)))
                        .doOnComplete(() -> downloadCompleted.postValue(Response.success(null)))
                        .subscribe();
```

Now the issue is that I need to wait until first step is done to make the next one and this is not happening now.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: whats wrong with your current approach?

Comment: Thanks in advance. See edit.

Comment: so it sounds like the `downloadListOfProducts` and `downloadListOfIngredients` are observables of two different types. is that correct?

Comment: That's correct. I have to download a series of items. Some are of type Product and some are of type Ingredient. OnNext i just add the items to a list (one list per type) and onComplete I add the lists to a database

Comment: i see. ultimately i would recomend splitting this into multiple observables rather than just one chain. also some other combination methods may be helpful https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Combining-Observables

Comment: I have succeeded a little bit. Now the whole chain is executed. The only problem is that I need to wait until the first step is done to make the next ones.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194189/discussion-between-william-reed-and-aldridge1991).

Comment: Have you tried using zip?
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html